# PHP library to generate user friendly relative timestamps

Tags: php, date, time

I'm looking for a PHP **library** that generates user-friendly representations of times - for example "two hours ago" when the timestamp is `time() - 2 * 3600`.

There are several existing questions with answers and blog posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670161/how-to-create-a-friendly-date-format-for-example-submitted-2-days-ago), [3](http://snipt.net/pkarl/pkarlcom-contextualtime/)), but all only contain code snippets - not a library I can install and upgrade.

[Django has one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/), Python also has a [standalone lib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-pretty/1), Javascript has several ([1](http://timeago.yarp.com/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641791/javascript-library-for-human-friendly-relative-date-formatting), [3](https://github.com/azer/relative-date)), too - where is the PHP library?

---

A library should have the following things:

- documentation
- PEAR installable
- regular releases
- (optional) translations

Comment: What qualifies as a library in the context of your question?

Comment: Any reason not to use a JavaScript library?

Comment: I don't want to rely on javascript since the target audience people use browsers like lynx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there didn't seem to be any library, I've made one myself and got it included in PEAR:

**Date_HumanDiff**, http://pear.php.net/package/Date_HumanDiff

Code is at http://github.com/pear/Date_HumanDiff

Answer (score 3):

I know [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) has one, you can propably port it easily.

The function is called `fuzzy_span()`.

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Date#fuzzy_span

Comment: a +1 for the link, which webbandit's answer didn't have

Answer (score 1):

Kohana Date class provides `fuzzy_span()` method for this. But it can't reply you exact values like "10 minutes"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$current_date_time_get_updated_on_date_format = '';

function get_updated_on_date_format($dt_updated, $prefix = 'Updated ', $at = 'at ') {
    global $current_date_time_get_updated_on_date_format;

    if ($current_date_time_get_updated_on_date_format == '') {
        $current_date_time_get_updated_on_date_format = now();
    }

    $i_second_now         = strtotime($current_date_time_get_updated_on_date_format);
    $i_second_dt_updated  = strtotime($dt_updated);
    $i_second_diff        = $i_second_now - $i_second_dt_updated;
    $s_return_date_format = '';

    if ($i_second_diff < 0) {
        // Developers Uploading Time, Time Zone Gap Patch
        $s_return_date_format = $prefix . $at . date('g:ia \o\n F jS, Y', strtotime($dt_updated));
    } else if ($i_second_diff < 60) {
        $s_return_date_format = $prefix . $i_second_diff . ' seconds ago ';
    } elseif ($i_second_diff < (60 * 60)) {
        $s_return_date_format = $prefix . round(($i_second_diff / 60), 0) . ' minitues ago ';
    } elseif ($i_second_diff < (60 * 60 * 24)) {
        $s_return_date_format = $prefix . round(($i_second_diff / (60 * 60)), 0) . ' hours ago ';
    } else {
        $s_return_date_format = $prefix . $at . date('g:ia \o\n F jS, Y', strtotime($dt_updated));
    }

    return $s_return_date_format;

}

function now() {
    // it should extract database time in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
    return mysql_now_value;
}
```

Comment: I did specifically ask for a library, and not a snippet of code.