# difference in time

Tags: php, date, time

I am quite confused on whether where to look for the solution on this one. I initially used DateTime::diff to this problem, however, the server this time has PHP version < 5.3.

I am calculating time difference,

```
$beyond= $_POST['beyond']; // 2012-01-07
$here= $_POST['here']; //2012-01-14
$interval = abs(strtotime($beyond) - strtotime($here));
```

The output of this is **604800**, I want to output this into string with a value of +7 or simply 7.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps

Comment: Hey, if you're using my code, please see my edit! I changed `86000` to `86400` that is the correct num of seconds in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
$beyond= "2012-01-07";
$here= "2012-01-15";
$interval = abs(strtotime($here) - strtotime($beyond));

$interval/= 86400;

echo round($interval);
```

Just get the time and divide for a day (86400 secunds in a day).

Comment: there could be problem with +/-1 hours.

Comment: round instead of floor may help