# PHP How do I calculate relative time?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: producing relative date/time from timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps)

Given a specific DateTime value, how do I display relative time, like

- 35 minutes ago
- 2 hours ago
- 3 days ago
- 1 month ago

etc, etc...?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = ".time()." WHERE id = ".$userID);
```

Comment: Its just an example. Thanks tho.

Comment: @JackManey I don't think you can tell someone that their code is vulnerable to SQL Injection when you have no clue how they are getting the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the concern but its just an example of how I will add it to the DB

Comment: @JackManey And what if in the code, `$userId` is hardcoded as a number? You're *speculating* that his code is vulnerable without seeing if it **actually** is.

Comment: Everyone is so negative this mornign. Good bye stack overflow.  See you when you've calmed down a bit.

Comment: I agree. I have 2 down votes for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

this may help you

```
function time_ago_en($time)
{
    if(!is_numeric($time))
        $time = strtotime($time);

    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "age");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","100");

    $now = time();

    $difference = $now - $time;
    if ($difference <= 10 && $difference >= 0)
        return $tense = 'just now';
    elseif($difference > 0)
        $tense = 'ago';
    elseif($difference < 0)
        $tense = 'later';

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    $period =  $periods[$j] . ($difference >1 ? 's' :'');
    return "{$difference} {$period} {$tense} ";
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php
echo time_ago_en(time() - 300); // 5 minutes ago
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` is a nice function

let me be more specific

```
strtotime(-5 days);
```

or

```
strtotime(-1 month);
```

There is an optional 2nd argument which is another time stamp of the time you want to start at, giving your `relative` time.  Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function relativeTime($time = false, $limit = 86400, $format = 'g:i A M jS') {
    if (empty($time) || (!is_string($time) &amp;&amp; !is_numeric($time))) $time = time();
    elseif (is_string($time)) $time = strtotime($time);

    $now = time();
    $relative = '';

    if ($time === $now) $relative = 'now';
    elseif ($time > $now) $relative = 'in the future';
    else {
        $diff = $now - $time;

        if ($diff >= $limit) $relative = date($format, $time);
        elseif ($diff < 60) {
            $relative = 'less than one minute ago';
        } elseif (($minutes = ceil($diff/60)) < 60) {
            $relative = $minutes.' minute'.(((int)$minutes === 1) ? '' : 's').' ago';
        } else {
            $hours = ceil($diff/3600);
            $relative = 'about '.$hours.' hour'.(((int)$hours === 1) ? '' : 's').' ago';
        }
    }

    return $relative;
}
?>
```

[Source](http://dev-tips.com/featured/creating-a-relative-time-function)

Comment: Can I see an example of what this would print?

Comment: It will print something like "now", "less than a minute ago", "about 4 seconds ago" or "about 41 hours ago". Nothing for years or months though, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I will be able to work out the rest for months and years. When will this come in? 'in the future'

Comment: If the given time is before now... in the future...

Comment: I just realised. Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of including "5 seconds on google" in your answer..?

Comment: @nbrogi Geez, this was 5 years ago..... Edited.