# PHP date strtotime - various output

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: producing relative date/time from timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps)

please see the example of PHP code:

```
<?php

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
$comment_added = date("2012-05-25 22:10:00");  

?>
```

As the output, I would like to get something like this (depending on when a comment has been added):

```
Comment has been added 21 minutes ago.
Comment has been added 15 hours ago.
Comment has been added 2 days ago.
Comment has been added 3 months ago.
Comment has been added 4 years ago.
```

I would like to get a function, where it will be selected automatically. Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: It is such an obvious duplicate that I am not going to even bother flagging it.

Comment: If so, can you paste the url ? Why always people saying "it's duplicate" without pasting correct url? The whole internet will be soon one big duplicate :]

Comment: See [Calculating relative time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculating-relative-time). It's C# but you should have no trouble converting it to PHP, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Guy: Obvious for you. It doesn't mean it is obvious for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
<?php

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
$comment_added = date("2012-05-25 22:10:00");

$diff = strtotime($now) - strtotime($comment_added);
if ($diff > (365*24*3600)) {
    $type = 'year';
    $value = floor($diff / (365*24*3600));
} else if ($diff > (30*24*3600)) {
    $type = 'month';
    $value = floor($diff / (30*24*3600));
} else if ($diff > (24*3600)) {
    $type = 'day';
    $value = floor($diff / (24*3600));
} else if ($diff > 3600) {
    $type = 'hour';
    $value = floor($diff / 3600);
} else if ($diff > 60) {
    $type = 'min';
    $value = floor($diff / 60);
} else {
    $type = 'sec';
    $value = $diff;
}

$plurial = '';
if ($value > 1)
{
    $plurial .= 's';
}
echo "Comment added {$value} {$type}{$plurial} ago.";

?>
```