# Easier way for PHP date calculations?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to determine when a user has last logged on.  My current method works but is there an easier way of determining this so that I could determine last X hours etc?

This is what I currently use:

```
$last_login_di = getdate($last_login);

$now = time();
$now_di = getdate($now);
$today = mktime(0,0,0,$now_di['mon'],$now_di['mday'], $now_di['year']);
if ($last_login > $today) {
    return 'Online Today';
}

$yesterday = $now-86400;
$yesterday_di = getdate($yesterday);
$yesterday = mktime(0,0,0,$yesterday_di['mon'],$yesterday_di['mday'], $yesterday_di['year']);
if ($last_login > $yesterday) {
    return 'Online Yesterday';
}

if (($now - $last_login < 604800) ) {
    return 'Online This Week';
}

....
```

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps?

Comment: Don't use getdate, then. just use the raw timestamps. `$diff = $now - $last_login` would give you a simple difference in seconds, which you can trivially turn back into hours/minutes/days.

Comment: Do NOT do "$yesterday = $now-86400;", as not all days are long 86400 seconds! (=24 hours) Unless you are using UTC everywhere, some days will likely be of 25 hours, and some of 23...

Answer (score 3):

[Try strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (see [relative formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) it accepts) or better yet, the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes.

For example, the `$yesterday` variable creation is prone errors near datetime savings. `strtotime()` handles this properly with:

```
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day');
```

While the $last_login check can be written like:

```
if (strtotime('-1 week') < $last_login) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to support different timezones you probably better of with the `DateTime` objects though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the DateTime and related classes [DateTime Book on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).  The [DateInterval class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) may be of particular use to you.

Answer (score 1):

How do you get the date? Using MySQL? Use UNIX_TIMESTAMP for dates, eg `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login) AS last_login_timestamp FROM ...` Then you can better calculate in PHP (using date_diff)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code's fine. But the `$yesterday` var is wrong.
It should be:

```
$yesterday = $today - 86400;
```

In your code `$yesterday` means `$a_day_ago`.

The same for the last week.

Comment: This will not always work: not all days are 86400 seconds long! (unless your server is configured to use UTC)

Comment: I just copied Paul's code, I just wanted to focus on the difference between *yesterday* and *a day ago*. Thank you for the point.

Answer (score 0):

You should heavily use the date objects built-in with PHP.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
$lastWeek = new DateTime('last week');
```

Now you are able to to any comparison logic you want, using the basic comparison operators:

```
if ($last_login > $now) {
    ...
} else if ($last_login > $yesterday) {
    ...
} else if ($last_login > $lastWeek) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

If you choose not to use the objects, try to avoid the `time()` function. That makes unit testing impossible. Tests should never depend on environment.

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` instead so you can mock it later.