# Classifying objects under the correct day

Tags: php, time, while-loop, strtotime

```
---Today---
<div>Object 99</div>
<div>Object 87</div> 
<div>Object 55</div>
---Yesterday---
<div>Object 44</div>
<div>Object 43</div>
<div>Object 40</div>
---June 8---
<div>Object 33</div>
<div>Object 20</div>
<div>Object 19</div>
--June 7---
<div>Object 15</div>
```

I have objects sorted by date, most recent first. I am running a while loop to go through the objects fetched from mysqli. They are being echoed into divs. For each date change I would like to add the date above the set for that date and "Today" or "Yesterday" if suitable. To figure out if its yesterday/today I use `if($object['time'] >= strtotime("yesterday"))` but how would I find the most recent message of each day to categorize it like the diagram above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly simple use a loop to build a new array,  then use a function like the one here to specify today or yesterday

[PHP: producing relative date/time from timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps)

```
foreach ($Objects as $Object)
{
 $Values[$object['time']]['Items'][] =  $object;
 $Values[$object['time']]['RelativeDateString'] = time2str($object['time']);
}

foreach ($Values as $Value){
  echo $Value['RelativeDateString'] ;
  foreach($Value['Items] as $Item){
    echo "\n<Div>" . $Item;

}
}
```

Comment: Needs some cleaning up but this performs great! Just trying to get "Today" instead of "2 hours ago"