# get time from database and echo time elapsed

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the `date_time` data from **my database** and echo it as in the format -

Example: `added 7 hours ago` , `added 8 minutes ago`

I've used the following code for this approach, but my code prints only the string `added ago`, with no elapsed time data in it. The function seems okay, but I don't know where did I mess up my code.

Thanks for any help.

```
//Calculating Time Elapsed
    function humanTiming ($time)
{
    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ 
    $time = strtotime($row['dt']);   
    $temp = humanTiming($time);
    echo 'added ' .$temp. ' ago';
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: See the DateTime::diff in Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: The function seems to work okay, as long as input isn't `0`. In that case, nothing is returned as in your case. Perhaps check what `strtotime()` returns?

Comment: It returns `1422826850`

Answer (score 0):

1422826850 is 02/01/2015 @ 9:40pm (UTC), current is 02/01/2015 @ 1:48pm (UTC).

The `humanTiming` function can only deal with the past time not the future.

Maybe you can get some idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690541/692076