# Convert string of UTC time to more readable format

Tags: php, string, date, time

I'm receiving a string containing date and time (in UTC format) for when something was created. The string looks like this: `"Wed Mar 13 14:10:20 +0000 2013"`. Now, I need to convert that to a more readable format. Something like this `"14:10, 13 Mar"` or preferably `"1 hour ago"`, `"1 week ago"` etc.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/strtotime http://php.net/date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dt = 'Wed Mar 13 14:10:20 +0000 2013';
echo date( 'h:i, d-M', strtotime( $dt ) );
```

The time difference will require more code.

Comment: That just gives me "12:00, 01-Jan" on everything... :/

Comment: This worked for some reason: `date('H:i, d M', strtotime($dt));`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime` object. The constructor should be able to parse that timestamp, then you can mainpulate the date and output in any format you wish:

```
$date = new dateTime('Wed Mar 13 14:10:20 +0000 2013');
echo $date->format('h:i, d-M');
```

For relative times, see: [Convert 2010-04-16 16:30:00 to "Tomorrow Afternoon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643113/convert-2010-04-16-163000-to-tomorrow-afternoon/2643137)